# LIBGDX: Where is AssetManager.isLoaded(AssetDescriptor)? Why there is none?

Tags: libgdx, asset-management

I know I can use `AssetManager.isLoaded(AssetDescriptor.filename, AssetDescriptor.type)`.
But, why there is no `AssetManager.isLoaded(AssetDescriptor)`method?

Comment: Vote to close because you know how to solve it and there isn't really a problem here. It's not there because nobody implemented it. libGDX is open source and available on github. Propose a pull request with the method if you think it's useful.

Comment: I understand, but can't find the close button on the this page.